# How to change the image src on click using only CSS but not JS

Tags: html, css

I need to change the src of the image on mouse click only with css
like

```
img:active {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [element replacement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#element_replacement) feature of the `content` property to achieve this.

Note that you can't set any ARIA or other accessibility related features using this technique so the information you convey will likely be lost to a portion of your user base. (This might be illegal depending on what that information is, who you are, and what control you are in / selling to).

You may wish to set `tabindex` or wrap the image in a button to make it keyboard/etc accessible.

Also note that `:active` means "While being clicked on" and not "After being clicked on". CSS doesn't have an "after being clicked on" pseudo-class (although `:focus` can suffice in some circumstances).

```css
img:active {
    content: url(http://placekitten.com/200/200);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt="">
```

Comment: Can't make the new image stay even after the image got clicked ?

Comment: @Vishnupriya — I thought I made that pretty clear in the final paragraph of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can not manipulate the src of an image just by css. But you could try using the image as background for the parent of the image and change the background via css just like:

```
.image-parent { background-image: url('myurl...')} ;
.image-parent:active {background-image: url('anotherurl...')}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Will this image stay after being clicked?

Comment: @Vishnupriya — No. The behaviour of `:active` is as I described in my answer.

Comment: @Vishnupriya – as Quentin mentioned it is not permanent. If you really want to manipulate the DOM (i.E. change the src of a img tag) permanent you would need to use JavaScript.